# Append a generated script after a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Have this code :

```
<script>
(function()
{
    let relScript = document.createElement('script');
    relScript.src="https://mountain.com/assets/js/sso.js";
    relScript.type  = "text/javascript";
    relScript.async  = true;
    relScript.defer  = true;
    $('.skip-page').append(relScript);
})();
</script>
```

The script is attached to body and not to this `<div class="skip-page">`;

My goal is to put this script after the div `skip-page`; Any ideas why is append to body ?

Comment: Looks fine to me - https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/ybeodvkL/ Can you elaborate on `"The script is attached to body"`

Comment: Why do you think you you need it "attached" to a specific div?   A script doesn't work differently depending on what the parent element of the `script` tag is.  It's the content of the script that's relevant.  Is it the script you've provided or the sso.js that's relevant?

Comment: You can use `.after()` or `.insertAfter()` depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

using load event

```js
// not use JQuery
window.onload = function (){
    let relScript = document.createElement('script');
    relScript.src="https://mountain.com/assets/js/sso.js";
    relScript.type  = "text/javascript";
    relScript.async  = true;
    relScript.defer  = true;
    $('.skip-page').append(relScript);
};

// Using JQuery
$(function(){
    let relScript = document.createElement('script');
    relScript.src="https://mountain.com/assets/js/sso.js";
    relScript.type  = "text/javascript";
    relScript.async  = true;
    relScript.defer  = true;
    $('.skip-page').append(relScript);
});
```

Comment: This answer does not address OP's primary question: *to put this script after the div `skip-page`*.